# PHP and SweetAlert using a Loop

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert

I'm trying to use sweetalert (a replacement for JavaScript's alert)  in php

but I don't know how to use it with a loop.

*Thanks for any help.*

This is what i have so far, but its not giving me any errors and it doesn't work :(

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweetalert.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#SweetAlert<?php echo($contact_id);?>").click(function() {
    sweetAlert({
        title: "Make Changes ?",
        text: "You Are about to Change <?php echo($contact_lastname);?> (<?php echo($splitName[0]);?> - <?php echo($splitName[1]);?>)",
        type: "warning" ,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#2e8c37",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, Continue",
        cancelButtonText: "No, Cancel",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: true 
    },
    function(isConfirm){
        if (isConfirm) {
            window.location.href = 'main.php?id=<?php echo($contact_id);?>&groupid=<?php echo($group_id);?>&unit=<?php echo($contact_lastname);?>';
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
// PHP LOOP: START

echo("<A HREF=\"#\" id=\"SweetAlert$contact_id\"><img src=\"button_ok_2.png\" onmouseover=\"this.style.cursor='pointer'\" border=\"0\" border=\"0\" title=\"Name # $contact_lastname\"></A>\n");

// PHP LOOP: END
```

Comment: *"it's not working"* is not a proper actionable problem statement

Comment: @charlietfl The code is what I have so far, its not givimg me any errors and its does not work. What else you want me to say/add ?

Comment: does the javascript exist after each element in the loop so that when it runs that element already exists?

Comment: @charlietfl yes, it exists after each element so I dont see why it doesnt work? It calls SweetAlert1,SweetAlert2, and so on for all of them even if I rename it to something else like: test1,test2 still nothing, not even an error :(

Comment: create a demo that reproduces issue in jsfiddle.net or other sandbox site

Comment: I've posted an answer. Please give it a try and see if it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can set a `css class` to all of your "Sweet Alert Links" so you can capture them all by jquery like like this: `<a class="SweetAlertLink" ...` then you do not need `id` for them to select them by `id`(although you can do it with `id`, but it's easier with `class`) - you do not need to assign any css for this class in your css. This is just to be able to select all of these specific links in jquery

Then You can use `data` attribute to set different data for each link and then use it in your jquery. So you can have `<a <a class="SweetAlertLink" data-contact_lastname="Lastname-1" ...` This means this record's lastname is "Lastname-1", So you can set all of these data in your loop like this: `<a class="SweetAlertLink" data-contact_lastname="'.$contact_lastname.'"...`

And then in your jquery you can access these data attributes like this: `$(this).data("contact_lastname")` in your `$(".SweetAlertLink").click(function() {`method.

But because in the `function(isConfirm){` `this` does no refer to `<a>` tag any more, we have to assign an object to the `<a>` element at the beginning of the `$(".SweetAlertLink").click(function() {` method like this `curObj = $(this);` and then in the `function(isConfirm){` function refer to this object instead of `this` like this: `curObj.data("contact_lastname")`

So your code will look like this:

**JavaScript**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweetalert.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var curObj;
    $(".SweetAlertLink").click(function() {
        curObj = $(this);
        sweetAlert({
            title: "Make Changes ?",
            text: "You Are about to Change "+$(this).data("contact_lastname")+" ("+$(this).data("split_name1")+" - "+$(this).data("split_name2")+")",
            type: "warning" ,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#2e8c37",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, Continue",
            cancelButtonText: "No, Cancel",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: true 
        },
        function(isConfirm){
            if(isConfirm){
                window.location.href = 'main.php?id='+curObj.data("contact_id")+'&groupid='+curObj.data("group_id")+'&unit='+curObj.data("contact_lastname");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**php**

```
<?php
// PHP LOOP: START

$string = '<a class="SweetAlertLink" href="#" id="SweetAlert'.$contact_id.'" data-contact_lastname="'.$contact_lastname.'" data-split_name1="'.$splitName[0].'" data-split_name2="'.$splitName[1].'" data-contact_id="'.$contact_id.'" data-group_id="'.$group_id.'">';
$string .= '<img src="button_ok_2.png" onmouseover="this.style.cursor=\'pointer\'" border="0" border="0" title="Name # '.$contact_lastname.'">';
$string .= '</a><br>';
echo $string;

// PHP LOOP: END
?>
```

**Note1:** With this method, you do not need to have the JavaScript code after each element and you only need to have this JavaScript code at the top of you page in your `<head>` section

**Note2:** I assume that you have correct values in the php variables in your loop like `$contact_id` or `$contact_lastname` or `$group_id` or ...

**Note3:** I have given some temporary names to the `data` attributes like `data-contact_lastname` or `data-contact_id` or ... You can change them to whatever suits your needs. But remember, if you change them, you have to change them both in your `php` and in your corresponding `JavaScript` code...

Comment: Flawless!! (احسان) Thanks sooooo much!! Best thing is I dont have to have javascript after each element, so now my source code is 100 times smaller. THANKS FOR EXISTING :) AND THANKS FOR YOUR HELP VERY MUCH.

Comment: You are welcome and WOW, you know how to write my name :)